# How can I collect data through a drupal form?

Tags: database

I want to allow users to contribute posts to my site. Should I set up a content type that can be created by the public or set up a new user role and get people to sign up first? I want to reduce the friction of adding a post to the absolute minimum.

Comment: It isn't related to Drupal per se.

Comment: For a Drupal module that lowers the threshold of contributing to the site while still protecting against spam, check out [Anonymous Publishing](https://drupal.org/project/anonymous_publishing).

Answer (score 1):

I'd let users login first to prevent spam. However you could simplify the registration&login process by having users authenticate with OpenID (Google, facebook ect.) Similar as what stackexchange offers.

This should get you started: https://drupal.org/project/openid_connect